# Access control on Azure SQL Data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure

Access Control setup on Tables inside `dbo` schema.

We are Denying select permission on some tables inside dbo schema as these tables have some critical data.

Issue: Even when Select query fails on the object. A user having create view grants can create a view on the same object.

Sample queries:

```
Select * from dbo.TABLE1 -- Fails as user does not have access.

Create view USER.VIEW1 as (Select * from dbo.TABLE1) -- this goes through.
```

How can I restrict this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this on Azure, but on my local SQL Server 2016, I cannot reproduce what you're seeing.  Perhaps the target user has more rights than you think?  Do they have membership in a role that is giving them access?

Anyway, the testbed I used to test this is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable
(
    SomeTable_id int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT SomeTable_pk
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE USER UserA WITHOUT LOGIN;
DENY SELECT ON dbo.SomeTable TO UserA;
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO UserA;
GRANT CREATE SCHEMA TO UserA;


EXECUTE AS USER = N'UserA'; --anything past this point is executed using UserA's permissions

--fails with SELECT permission denied
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable;
GO

--this works due to the GRANT CREATE SCHEMA statement above
CREATE SCHEMA UserA;
GO

--this works due to the GRANT CREATE VIEW statement above
CREATE VIEW UserA.SomeTableView
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable;
GO

--this fails since the user who created the view doesn't have rights to the underlying table.
SELECT *
FROM UserA.SomeTableView;
DROP VIEW UserA.SomeTableView;

--revert back to "me" instead of UserA
REVERT
```

UserA is able to create the view, but they cannot actually select from it.  The error returned is:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 27
>   The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'SomeTable', database 'MaxTest', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: My Apologies for a very delayed response. Authorization was a problem here. I had created the roles with authorization db_owner (which is by default), after restricting this, i was able to achieve the access controls.

Something like this:
Create ROLE MYROLE AUTHORIZATION db_datareader.